# Why is BIP133 listed as 'Draft' when it has been implemented for years?

Tags: bip, soft-fork

BIP133 is listed as 'Draft' but it has been implemented since v.0.13.0

https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0133.mediawiki

Is there anything preventing it from being labelled as 'Final'?